# Replace dataframe value by indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've the dataframe `in`

```
import pandas as pd
in = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[1, 2],
    data= [['a','b'],['c','d']],
)
in
```

```
    1   2
0   a   b
1   c   d
```

and would like to replace single values (here: `d` with `z`) by indices (of row, column) resulting in a dataframe `out`:

```
    1   2
0   a   b
1   c   z
```

How can I replace a value by indices (here: row idx is 1, column idx is 1) most efficient (memory consumption, execution time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if want set values by positions (first value is `0`, because python counts from `0`):

```
df.iloc[1,1] = 'z'
```

Or if want set by labels (index and columns values) use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[1,2] = 'z'
```

---

If want set one value only better is use [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) or
[`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
#by positions
df.iat[1,1] = 'z'

#by labels
df.at[1,2] = 'z'
```

Comment: Ther is no more efficient implementation than your suggestion I guess...

Comment: @thinwybk - Added solution if need set one value only